# Ruby: Self reference in hash

Tags: ruby, hash, reference

Is it possible to reference one element in a hash within another element in the same hash?

```
# Pseudo code
foo = { :world => "World", :hello => "Hello #{foo[:world]}" }
foo[:hello] # => "Hello World"
```

Comment: as @jakup said not in 1 step, but do you want it if you change :world, that :hello changes as well?

Comment: Interesting question, why do you want to?

Comment: Are you building some kind of tree structure in a hash?

Comment: I'm passing an options hash in a method definition and one of my options relies on another one. This might be a bad design but it had me wonder what would be best and most Ruby-esque way of doing this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Indirectly perhaps...

```
foo = { :world => 'World', :hello => lambda { "Hello #{foo[:world]}" }}

puts foo[:hello].call
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to make values of some keys dependent on others:

```
foo = Hash.new{|h, k|
   case k
   when :hello; "Hello #{h[:world]}"
   when :bye; "Bye #{h[:world]}"
   end
}
foo[:world] = 'World'
foo[:hello] # => 'Hello World'
foo[:bye] # => 'Bye World'
foo[:world] = 'Heaven'
foo[:hello] # => 'Hello Heaven'
foo[:bye] # => 'Bye Heaven'
```

Answer (score 4):

This can't be done directly because `""` is strictly evaluated.

Use of a lazy-value generator (e.g. lambda/proc) with later evaluation is required.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

No.

At least not in one step. You could do something like:

```
foo = {world: "hello"}
foo[:hello] = "Hello #{foo[:world]}"
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I figured. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can!

```
options = { :deep => :stuff }
options.merge!(:options => options)

# It's the same at any depth...
options[:options][:options][:options][:options][:options]
  #=> {:deep=>:stuff, :options=>{...}}
```

Neat, huh?  The hash object in `options` has the same `object_id` as the value assigned to `:options`.

Answer (score 0):

`Object#tap` gives you a nice way to complete the Object initialisation with extra self-references.

```
{ foo: 1 }.tap { |obj| obj[:bar] = obj.fetch(:foo)}
```